# dependent: :destroy not working with validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I've been working with two models and form validations on nested attributes with uniquness.

When saving the form, the uniqueness validation is scoped to the the email address of the list user. I encountered a bug where if the user tried to save two emails in the one transaction the validation is not fired because it checks against existing records in the database, rather than objects in memory which are about to be saved.

My models are as follows:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :competitors, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :list
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :competitors, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end


class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :list, inverse_of: :competitors

  validates :list, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: User::EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :list_id }

end
```

To fix this, I added:

```
validates_associated :competitors
```

to my list model which now causes the form to behave as expected with the validation firing off when the user tries to save two email addresses for competitors which are the same.

However, running my tests, I found that the example in this block is now causing a failure.

```
describe "@competitors" do
  let!(:list) { FactoryGirl.create(:list) }
  let!(:competitor) { FactoryGirl.create(:competitor, list_id: list.id) }

  it "deletes associated competitors if the list is deleted" do
    expect { list.destroy }.to change { Competitor.count }.by(-1)
  end
end
```

My research so far tells me that this is not a common problem, so I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't quite tell what that is.

I'm using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. After spending hours on this I worked out that for the failing tests, there were multiple, that I just needed to reload the list from the test database.

So in this instance:

```
it "deletes associated competitors if the list is deleted" do
  expect { list.reload.destroy }.to change { Competitor.count }.by(-1)
end
```

solved it, and the others that were affected.